# CSS3 translateX not working

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to animate several items on screen when a menu item is clicked...all animations but one are working as desired. I want to move in the main content (section) of the page from right to left but instead of sliding in it just appears without any transition. This is the relevant css code:

```
section{
  width: 920px;
  background: rgb(247, 239, 239);
  position: absolute;
  left: 2000px;
  top: 240px;
  padding:20px;
}
.fadeInRight{
  -webkit-transition: 1s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: 1s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: 1s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: 1s ease-in-out;
  transition: 1s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-2000px);
  -moz-transform: translateX(-2000px);
  -ms-transform: translateX(-2000px);
  -o-transform: translateX(-2000px);
  transform: translateX(-2000px);
}
```

html code:

```
<section id="content" class="fadeInRight">


</section>
```

you can see the code in action [here](http://focusfotos.com.mt/v1/) once you click on one of the links in the footer.

Any advise is much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Specify a property that has to be animated:

```
.fadeInRight{
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 1s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: -moz-transform 1s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: -ms-transform 1s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: -o-transform 1s ease-in-out;
  transition: transform 1s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-2000px);
  -moz-transform: translateX(-2000px);
  -ms-transform: translateX(-2000px);
  -o-transform: translateX(-2000px);
  transform: translateX(-2000px);
}
```